# Javascript or PHP framework for frontend?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

We're developing a site with complex views and a lot of ajax requests. Will it be better to separate the view into a standalone application powered by a JS framework?

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a server-side scripting language, which means that it cannot be used on the client side.

What you can do is use PHP on the server and use a Javascript framework (like Angular) on the client.